# Including a file from another that is not main.rs nor lib.rs

Tags: module, rust

(I'm a Rust beginner) I have three files : main.rs, board.rs and case.rs.
I want to include case.rs into board.rs, and board.rs into main.rs, so the board uses the case, and we can access the board in main.

I've successfully added the board into main, but the way I did doesn't seem to work for the second part.

I've tried to encapsulate every file's content into "mod {}" but it doesn't change the problem.
Also I tried every combinations of "mod" and "use".

Every file is in the folder src/, and I'd like them not to move from there if possible.

main.rs

```rust
mod board;

fn main() {
    let mut b: Board = Board::new();
}
```

board.rs

```rust
mod case;

pub struct Board {
    board: [ Case; 9 ]
}

// There is also the impl part of course, let's keep it short
```

case.rs

```rust
pub enum Case { Empty, Full(Player) }
```

Using VSCode with the Rust plugin, the "case" word on the first line of the board.rs file is underlined red, and it says :

"src/case.rs
file not found for module `case`
help: name the file either board\case.rs or board\case\mod.rs inside the directory "src""

Why doesn't it search in the current directory?

Comment: "let's keep it short" -- you should always try to provide [ReprEx](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your files could look like as follows:

case.rs:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
struct Player;

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
pub enum Case {
    Empty,
    Full(Player)
}
```

board.rs:

```rust
use crate::case::Case;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Board {
    board: [ Case; 9 ]
}

impl Board {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { board: [Case::Empty; 9] }
    }
}
```

main.rs:

```rust
mod case;
mod board;

use crate::board::Board;

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", Board::new());
}
```

Basically you create a `crate` (a binary one, because of your `main.rs`) and that `crate` can have modules.  A module can be a file, or it can be a folder as well (if it happens to have a `mod.rs`).  (And for the sake of completeness, it could also be an *inline* module without direct relation to the file system.)

Your `mod` statements (the ones which are indicating files and folders, not the ones which you use to create inline modules) should either be placed at the top level of your `crate` (e.g. in your `main.rs` or `lib.rs`) or at the module levels (in your `mod.rs` files) depending on the desired structure.

For further info on this, please read the The Rust Programming Language book's relevant chapter: [Packages and Crates](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-01-packages-and-crates.html).

Comment: Ok this took me a while to understand that the "mod" call in the beginning of main.rs file kind of "registered" the use of the module for the rest of the files. Thank you very much, this is very clear!